# C++ direct and copying initialization problem with constructor

Tags: c++

I have started doing C++ clases for over 2 weeks now and I have a small problem that i dont know how to solve. I have to make a simple Class with one int parameter. That class needs to work with direct and copying initilaization and needs to print message which initialization is used. For example:

```
TestClass T(60) //this should print a message "Direct initialization"

TestClass T = 205 // this should print a messagte "Copying initialization"
```

Comment: Think of the type of constructor that is called in each case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constructors-cpp?view=vs-2019 introduces constructors if you are not aware of different kinds of constructors in C++.

Comment: Please ask an actual question. What problems did you encouter?

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what material was taught in, supposedly, this formal C++ class, before you were given this assignment? @MutableSideEffect -- feel free to try it yourself and observe that the same constructor gets called, value assignment in initialization is equivalent to plain ol' construction. That's not the root issue here.

Comment: Well after making explicit TestClass(int a) { number = a; std::cout << "Direct initialization" }; I have solved the problem for direct initialization but the problem is I dont know how to make any working constructor with copying initialization. I have tried 10000 things but none of them wored :/ I know that it is because of "explicit" thing but I really dont know how to prevent these two from mixing with each other

Comment: the compiler generates a = operator from the copy constructor. what is happening is that it is being implicitly converted to a TestClass, then copied to the original TesetClass

Comment: I have used the same "trcik" with double thing but i have to use "int" type strictly :/

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with your full code and any error messages you encounter

Answer (score 1):

If you use a constructor with a single variable initialization, then this assignment operation will be done for you automatically. See my code below:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class A {
    int x;

public:
    A(int xx) {
        cout << "Constructor Called" << endl;
        x = xx;
    }

    print() {
        cout << "Value of obj is " << x << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A v = 10;
    v.print();
}
```

Because you used initialization constructor, `=` operator was handled automatically. To prove that it is using the constructor, I used `cout` in constructor and created and called another printing function.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept the answer and upvote. :)

Comment: I hope you read this part "That class needs to work with direct and copying initilaization and needs to print message which initialization is used. For example:

TestClass T(60) //this should print a message "Direct initialization"

TestClass T = 205 // this should print a messagte "Copying initialization""

Comment: Avoid posting an answer to questions that are almost sure to close due to lack of information or proper SO formatting guidelines. Better post a comment to guide the OP on how to ask.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I have just started writing answers. thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h might also be interesting for you. Including the whole standard library in a non-portable way instead of just the `iostream`-header is quite a waste, isn't it?  Best you just forget this header ever existed ;)

Comment: @churill thanks for pointing it out. It is a bad habit of mine which grew during participating in competitive programming contests so that I won't have to think about adding headers later.